# SQL: convert 20071117183011 into date/time (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

How can I convert value like "20071117183011" into date/time? IS there anything besides splitting into substrings? (MySQL)

Comment: MySQL 5 (+ 6 more characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Oracle, you can use TO_DATE function.

```
TO_DATE("20071117183011", "YYYYMMDDHHMISS")
```

On MySQL, use STR_TO_DATE.

```
STR_TO_DATE('20071117183011', '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
```